# HTMLEditorExtender does not correctly load on Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net, htmleditorextender

I'm writing a web application that utilizes HTMLEditorExtender. I invoke it using the following code:

```
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="htmlTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" Width="90%" Rows="25" />
    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmlEditorExtender" TargetControlID="htmlTextBox" runat = "server" EnableSanitization="false" >
    <Toolbar> 
            <asp:Undo />
            <asp:Redo />
            <asp:Bold />
            <asp:Italic />
            <asp:Underline />
            <asp:ForeColorSelector />
            <asp:FontNameSelector />
            <asp:FontSizeSelector />
            <asp:JustifyLeft />
            <asp:JustifyCenter />
            <asp:JustifyRight />
            <asp:JustifyFull />
            <asp:InsertOrderedList />
            <asp:InsertUnorderedList />
            <asp:CreateLink />
            <asp:UnLink />
    </Toolbar>
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

*NOTE: I know it's bad to set EnableSanitization="false", but this application will only be used privately.*

With that code, when the page loads, the text box looks like this:

[image]

That looks good!

But, in my application, I navigate to another page and then need to navigate back to this page using Server.Transfer(page_URL). When I do that, the HTMLEditorExtender no longer loads correctly and I get something that looks like this:

[image]

How can I get it to load correctly on Server.Transfer()? I'm thinking that it may be a simply flag I need to invoke on the creation of the HTMLEditorExtender element, but I've tried a few and can't get anything to work.

EDIT: I should add that I am using IE 8 and it must work in IE 8.

Comment: Using FireBug in FireFox, do you see any scripts or other requests being denied?

Comment: @Brian Using firefox, the application has a different visual error. The white box with 'Cancel' in the top left isn't there. It's insted just an empty text box. The only thing I see in firebug that might be helpful is "TypeError: Sys.Extended is undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed stopped using Server.Transfer() and decided to set the PostBackUrl in the ASP. For some reason, this worked.